# Mismatch between the processor architecture of the project being built

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

I have 2 questions.

1. I am getting this warning and how can I resolve it (get rid of it) ?
2. What does it mean by a MSIL built ?

> There was a mismatch between the processor architecture of the project
> being built "MSIL" and the processor architecture of the reference
> "abc.dll", "x86". This mismatch may cause runtime failures. Please
> consider changing the targeted processor architecture of your project
> through the Configuration Manager so as to align the processor
> architectures between your project and references, or take a
> dependency on references with a processor architecture that matches
> the targeted processor architecture of your project.

What I tried so far.

1. I changed the target CPU to x86
2. Then went to configuration manager and changed the platform to x86, and active solution platform to x86.

When I cleaned - build I get the same warning.

Note: I am using visual studio 2022, and .net4.8.

System type: 64-bit operating system, x64-based processor

Comment: There is no setting named "target CPU" in the C# IDE, that makes it hard to guess what you did wrong.  The one that matters is "Platform target", Project > Properties > Build tab to change it.  Be sure to change it both for the Debug and Release configuration, combobox at the top of that same settings tab.

Answer (score 1):

> What does it mean by a MSIL built ?

That means it should support any platform. Since .net is runtime compiled it can support multiple platforms. MSIL would be equivalent to "Any CPU" platform target. But quite a few programs have some native dependencies, and need to run on the same platform as these dependencies, so are marked as only supporting a specific platform.

> I am getting this warning and how can I resolve it (get rid of it) ?

Since you say your project support any platform, but you depend on libraries that only support a specific platform. So if you where to run your program in x64 without any runtime checks, your program might fail when it tries to load the library.

Changing the target platform for the project should have resolved the error, but there might be multiple configurations and platforms that can have different settings, so it can be a bit of a mess to ensure everything is consistent. And even more so if you have lots of projects. I would suggest to check what specific project is giving the warning, and ensure that specific project is correctly configured.

Of course,  if your program runs well in x64, it might just be a spurious warning that may be ignored.

Comment: I guess the issue is form `abc.dll` as stated in the warning. I am not able to deploy the project which I guess is  because of this warning. This only hapend after upgrading from VS2019 to VS2022. Can you recommend an easy way to debug the issue to find the root cause ?

Comment: What @jonasH wrote is copletely correct. If you depend on a native dll you must compile your project with the architecture for which the dll was originally compiled. It's better to switch to a x64 version of abc.dll necause x86 is a old and mostly not supported architecture. You should find/compile a x64 versione of abd.dll

Comment: @Illep I have not switched to VS2022, so I have no idea if that works differently. But warnings should not prevent you from deploying your project. So I'm wondering if there is something else going on. As Marco Beninca writes it might be better to update to x64 if you have that option, even if x86 will be supported by windows and .Net for a fairly long time.